# Python theano cannot work "Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu:..."

Tags: python, theano

I wanna learn deeplearning and I am trying to install the Theano, but it cannot work, It has been bothering me a lot, please help me, thanks a lot!

```
5368 code
=====================================================

ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: ('nvcc return status', 2, 'for cmd', 'nvcc -shared -O3 -Xlinker /DEBUG -D HAVE_ROUND -m64 -Xcompiler -DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=c72d035fdf91890f3b36710688069b2e,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD -ID:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda -ID:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include -ID:\\Anaconda2\\include -ID:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\gof -o C:\\Users\\tree\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.11-64\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd mod.cu -LD:\\Anaconda2\\libs -LD:\\Anaconda2 -lcublas -lpython27 -lcudart')
mod.cu

['nvcc', '-shared', '-O3', '-Xlinker', '/DEBUG', '-D HAVE_ROUND', '-m64', '-Xcompiler', '-DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=c72d035fdf91890f3b36710688069b2e,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD', '-ID:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda', '-ID:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include', '-ID:\\Anaconda2\\include', '-ID:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\gof', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\tree\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.11-64\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd', 'mod.cu', '-LD:\\Anaconda2\\libs', '-LD:\\Anaconda2', '-lcublas', '-lpython27', '-lcudart']
[Elemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<TensorType(float64, vector)>)]
```

Comment: it means it can not compile NVIDIA GPU's CUDA code. Just try to disable gpu and/or update theano.

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt thanks

Comment: Did you fix this ? I have the same problem. I want to use the GPU and im using the latest version of theano.

Comment: @ Anirudh GP sorry I forget its detail, I am using caffe and mxnet